# How to link GoDaddy domain to AWS classic Load Balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, elastic-load-balancer

I have bought domain from GoDaddy. Now, I have decided to use AWS to setup my web servers with load balancers. How can I link my domain to AWS classic load balancer?

I read the [Configure a Custom Domain Name](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/using-domain-names-with-elb.html) AWS documentation. They Have explained how to use their Route 53 service for this in detail but not alternative. I am looking for alternative methods and procedures in detail.

I have tried CNAME approach. I tried setting CNAME entry like host is api.xxxx.co.in and pointed to (my load balancer's DNS) lb-xxxx-2341234.elb.aws.com but it doesn't take it on GoDaddy's DNS manager page. I get an error. I have further problem that i want web request go to 8080 instead of 80. I am not sure how that will be handled either. Lack of documentation. Currently i am doing Subdomain forwarding but i am getting 405 for POST methods. I think, i am getting 405 because I am forwarding subdomain. It might be considered as cross domain. I don't know.

Comment: Did you set CNAME from godaddy panel?

Comment: I tried setting CNAME entry like host is api.xxxx.co.in and pointed to (my load balancer's DNS) lb-xxxx-2341234.elb.aws.com but it doesn't take it. I have further problem that i want web request go to 8080 instead of 80. I am not sure how that will be handled either. Lack of documentation. Currently i am doing Subdomain forwarding but i am getting 405 for POST methods. I think, i am getting 405 because I am forwarding subdomain. It might be considered as cross domain. I don't know.

Comment: You can set your load balancer to listen 8080 port of your instance.

Comment: i have it setup listen on 8080 but when HTTP requests come, they default to port 80.